# Имеется или имеются?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

1. В его подчинении имеется/имеются несколько работников.
2. В распоряжении автоугонщика имеется/имеются несколько машин.

Имеется или имеются?

Какое правило обосновывает правильный ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае следует предпочесть единственное число: **имеется**.

Грамота.ру [говорит следующее](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo):

> **Согласование сказуемого при обозначении подлежащим приблизительного
>   количества**
>
> При подлежащем – количественном сочетании со значением
>   приблизительности предпочитается форма единственного числа сказуемого:
>   *Откроется несколько новых школ. На земле живет более трех миллиардов
>   людей.*  Но: *Лишь несколько студентов смогли решить эту задач*у; форма
>   множественного числа сказуемого обусловлена  «активностью» действующих
>   лиц, названных подлежащим.